# controller method checks does not work if goes back from browser in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have made an `view` which is passed to the `controller/method` having a  `url parameter` of `focus`.

Actually i am creating a user in my database. This controller check the `focus parameter` if it is already signed up or not.

If already signed go to the thank you page mentioning that you have already signed. It worked perfectly but when i create a user and thankyou page is shown and when i clicked the back from browser it goes to  the same signup form page. neglecting the controller/method logic. It should show the `thank you` page that this is already have been signed.

Here is my controller call for getting and checking the parameters.

```
function submituser()
    {

        $errorMessage = "You are not authorise to access this page.";
        $id = $this->request->getQuery('focus');
        if ($id) {
            $user_id = $id;

            $this->loadModel('Users');
            $responseData = $this->Users->getUsers($user_id);

            if($responseData['user']->converted==1){
                /*
                 * Show thank you page if user status is converted.
                 * */
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Signup', 'action' => 'completed']);
            }
            else{
                if (isset($responseData['user']['first_name'])) {
                    $this->viewBuilder()->Setlayout('usersignup');
                } else {
                    /*
                     * Flash Message
                     * */
                    $this->Flash->set($errorMessage);
                    $this->viewBuilder()->Setlayout('usersignup');
                }
            }

        } else {
            /*
             * Flash Message
             * */
            $this->Flash->set($errorMessage);
            $this->viewBuilder()->Setlayout('usersignup');
        }
    }
```

i tried to `var_dump` and `exit` the script when the controller is loaded but it run its previous script.

Comment: When you click back btn from browser, what will be included in this `$id = $this->request->getQuery('focus');`

Comment: There is id in the focus parameter. which check the status whether it is already have completed the signup procedure or not.

Comment: I think when you click back btn from browser, `focus` is gone and will go to last condition which is `$id` is empty

Comment: focus remained there and above the function i tried to `echo "test"` and `exit` the page but no success

Comment: The method is call via jquery or form get or post method ?

Comment: when the signup signing is completed i call the `window.location.href = $('#site_base_url').val()+'signup/completed';` which shows the thankyou page.

Comment: Why? You `redirect` method is not work ?

Comment: this worked when i hit `Ctrl+F5` otherwise it just shows the page.